# gitlab: change number of projects limit

Tags: gitlab

I've encountered the 10 projects limit in GitLab. I looked in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` and couldn't find a mention to that number or limit.

How can the 10 projects per person limit be changed?

I'm running GitLab CE 7.10.1-omnibus.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/10151

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your admin account to login to GitLab and visit `http://your_gitlab_host/admin/application_settings` to change `default_projects_limit` value as you wish.

Comment: I have changed this but this does not seem to work? I.e., even after setting this to be 35, the limit is still 10.

Comment: At the left bottom of the settings page there is a green button "Save", did you happen to forget click save after you modified the limit value?

Answer (score 6):

Already created users will retain the lower limit, even after you boost it. Think of the systemwide limit as a number applied only when users get created. I had to edit the individual user to set the limit higher, since it didn't pick up on the increased default limit. The URL for the individual user is here:

`/admin/users/HANDLE/edit`